# Why am I getting undefined when fetching a list of posts?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

I am trying to fetch a list of posts form jsonplaceholder with nextjs and axios.

This is my ListOfPosts.jsx

```
import Link from "next/link";
import axios from "axios";


export default function ListOfPosts({posts}) {
    return(
        <div>
            {posts.map(post => (
                <div key={post.id}>
                    <Link href={`/posts/${post.id}`}>{post.body}</Link>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
        
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    console.log(response.data);
    const posts = response.data;
    return {
        props: {
            posts
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my posts/page.jsx

```
import ListOfPosts from "./ListOfPosts";

export default async function PostsPage({posts}) {
    return (
        <>
            <section>
                <ListOfPosts posts={posts}/>
            </section>
        </>
    )
}
```

The error i am getting is `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` at ListOfPosts.jsx

What am i doing wrong when trying to fetch posts with axios?

Comment: Which do you use directory `/app` or `/pages`? I recommend the `/app` directory, and no need `getStaticProps` function.

Comment: 1. console.log showing the expected data? 
2. successfully got the data at "ListOfPosts" component? (check, you can use console.log)

Make sure the both answer positive and then apply "optional chaining" [ posts?.map ]

Comment: @Emre i am ussing /app directory. Which is the best way of fetching data using this directory?

Comment: @tukitooo1998 Please, read this page https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching. I also answered your question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `getStaticProps` function in the `/app` directory.

```js
async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    // The return value is *not* serialized
    // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.

    // Recommendation: handle errors
    if (!res.ok) {
        // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
    }

    return res.json()
}

export default async function Page() {
    const data = await getData()

    return <main>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</main>
}
```

**Further readings:**

- [How to fetch data in Next.js (/app)](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching)
- [Why is the Second Argument in
  JSON.stringify() usually null?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-is-the-second-argument-in-json-stringify-usually-undefined/)

Comment: Ok great, so i get it no need with app directory to do the `getStaticProps` way. So given my structure which is the best practice to render the data? In the `posts/page.jsx` which is just the page that acts as a container? Or in the `ListOfPosts.jsx` which is the list of posts it self?

Comment: @tukitooo1998 it depends on what you want to do. You can create a layout if you're requesting the same data multiple times in a route, OR you can separate a route into components such as making "list" component. Maybe you could want to do client process on the list component in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props) only runs on the pages.

> getStaticProps can only be exported from a page. You cannot export it
> from non-page files, _app, _document, or _error.
>
> One of the reasons for this restriction is that React needs to have
> all the required data before the page is rendered.

you could use it inside `PostsPage` and pass it to `ListOfPosts` as prop.

if it is in app directory, those server side functions do not run on `app` directory. it only runs on `pages` directory.